# NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 't0.changeLang'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working in an app to draw a tree-graph for collage classes on screen.
I have the tree structured, every class have its own node and every node have a widget which is displayed on screen as part of the tree.
Everything is working as expected but when trying to add the option to change the language for the text on the node widgets I had an issue.

Here is my code:

```
class ClassNode {
  /*
  data fields to describe the class
  ...
  */

  NodeWidget nodeWidget; // widget of the node stored here
}
```

```
class NodeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ClassNode _class;
  Function(Lang) changeLang;

  NodeWidget(this._class);

  @override
  _NodeWidgetState createState() => _NodeWidgetState();
}

class _NodeWidgetState extends State<NodeWidget> {
  Lang lang;

  @override
  void initState() {
    lang = Lang.AR;
    widget.changeLang = (Lang newLang) {
      setState(() {
        lang = newLang;
      });
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(lang == Lang.AR ? widget._class.arName : widget._class.engName);
  }
}
```

```
class TreeViewer extends StatelessWidget {
  ClassTree classTree; // this contains all the classNodes

  void changeLang(Lang lang) {
    for (var classNode in classTree.list) {
      // here I get the error that changeLang is null!
      classNode.nodeWidget.changeLang(lang);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractiveViewer(
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

The ClassTree class:

```
class ClassTree {
  List<ClassNode> list = [];
  ClassNode root;

  static ClassTree create(String data) {
    var tree = ClassTree();
    
    while (dataNotFinished) {

      // proccess data ...

      var cn = ClassNode();

      // conect cn the tree data structure...

      cn.nodeWidget = NodeWidget(cn);
      list.add(cn);
    }
    return tree;
  }
}
```

In the TreeViewer class I get this error when trying to call changeLang:

> NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 't0.changeLang'

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hello, what is `ClassTree` and where is it defined?

Comment: @RukshanJS it is manages `ClassNode` objects, it has a property called `list` that contains all the `ClassNode` objects.
It is not directly related to any widget on the screen.. it's mainly to manage the nodes.

Comment: Yes but I don't see a definition for `ClassTree` here. Are you sure `classNode` in your `for (var classNode in classTree.list)` returns a ClassNode object?

Comment: @RukshanJS I added the definition in the question above, hope that will help.

Comment: @RukshanJS I think the problem is in the way I communicate between `NodeWidget` and `_NodeWidgetState`, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: In my case same problem was because of circular package dependency.